# wso2 api manager map publisher URL parameters to values

Tags: api, url, wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-integration-studio

There is article from wso2 [Map the Parameters of your Backend URLs with the API Publisher URLs](https://docs.wso2.com/m/mobile.action#page/57744145).

Within it we have how the complete publisher URL looks like:

```
http://<hostname>:8280/<context>/<version>/<API resource>
```

And the whole use case is:

> 2. You can define variables as part of the URI template of your API's
>      resources. For example, in the URI template
>      /business/{businessId}/address/, businessId is a variable.
> 3. The
>      variables in the resources are read during mediation runtime using
>      property values with the "uri.var." prefix. For example, this HTTP
>      endpoint gets the businessId that you specify in the resource
>      http://localhost:8280/businesses/{uri.var.businessId}/details.

I would like to access during mediation also `<version>` and `<context>` part of the publisher URL. However, when I use expression `uri.var.version` I will get the empty string. Or if I use the parameter value in `<context>` then I will get also empty string value.

My sample:

```
<context>: /test/{service}
<version>: 1.0
<API resource>: /{operation}/{account}

http://localhost:8280/test/{service}/1.0/{operation}/{account}
```

I am able to map parameters from `<API resource>`, it works like expected. But when I try to get `uri.var.service` or `uri.var.version` I will allways get empty string value.

Is it possible to somehow get values of parameters from `<context>` and `<version>` during mediation?