# Can we map the version value in the WSO2 Managed API endpoint URL?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am creating an API with some context path and v1 version:

[image]

Then I try to provide the sandbox and production endpoints pointing at the backends. The goal is to have the following:

**PRO:** `http://localhost:9090/myapi/{version}`

**SB:** `http://localhost:8080/myapi/{version}`

That is to say I would like to use the version field in the backend path.

[image]

However I am getting the following errors:

> Invalid Sandbox Endpoint URI. Please refer HTTP Endpoint documentation
>   of the WSO2 ESB for details.
>
> Invalid Production Endpoint URI. Please
>   refer HTTP Endpoint documentation of the WSO2 ESB for details.

Is there any way to do this?

**UPDATE:**

I have found the following article (https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Map+the+Parameters+of+your+Backend+URLs+with+the+API+Publisher+URLs) which explains how to map values using the uri.var prefix. So now in my endpoints I have:

**PRO:** `http://localhost:9090/myapi/{uri.var.version}`

**SB:** `http://localhost:8080/myapi/{uri.var.version}`

The problem now is that its value is empty.

Comment: Just to clarify the requirement better, What advantage do you expect by defining the version with a variable?

Comment: It is related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53720241/whats-the-recommended-way-to-define-url-patterns-and-versioning-for-backend-ser/53734861#53734861. Your solution there does help remove the context path, but not the version. Using this kind of replacement {version} would allow me to use URLs like http://WSO2/myapp/v1/api/customers which would be translated to a backend call /api/v1/customers with the variable replacement.

Comment: I'm still not very clear about the requirement. If you are trying to change where the version appears in the context path you can try to set context like "/wso2/myapp/{version}/api". I don't see an advantage of setting the backend service version using the API Manager API version.

Comment: The problem is the same as in the other question, having into account that the wso2 api version is the same as the backend version in the URL I was looking for a different way to solve that problem using the variable substitution

Comment: I just found this question that looks for the same approach: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48832995/wso2-api-manager-map-publisher-url-parameters-to-values?rq=1 But it doesn't have an answer to this specific problem either.

Comment: Getting version to the backend URL with a variable seems not straightforward. But you should be able to get this done with an In Flow mediator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to create an In Flow mediation policy to get the API Version to the endpoint URL.

For example, you can create a file called "VersionSequence.xml" and add the following content to that file. This sequence mediator will allow storing the REST API Version to a property called "uri.var.version".

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence name="VersionSequence" trace="disable" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <property expression="$ctx:SYNAPSE_REST_API_VERSION" name="uri.var.version"/>
    <log level="custom">
        <property expression="get-property('uri.var.version')" name="APIVersion"/>
    </log>
</sequence>
```

Then you can upload this mediation policy to **In-Flow** of the "**Enable Message Mediation**" section when **implementing** the API in API Manager. After that, you can set the endpoint as below which will get the version from "uri.var.version" property which you created in mediation flow.

[http://localhost:9090/myapi/{uri.var.version}](http://localhost:9090/myapi/%7Buri.var.version%7D)